# How to retain the zoom and refresh after setinterval using google maps

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi here i am developing tracking applicationsusing the angular web.For every 30 seconds i am able to render the data from the server here my issue is when ever i update the coordinates it refreshes the auto zoom i mean suppose if i am viewing the map at zoom :16 by zooming in after setinterval init it is displaying zoom level@10 then how i can retain zoom and center after refresh  and **Is there any way to update the markers with out using the set interval** below is my code

```
{
    "page": 2,

    "data": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "first_name": "Eve",
            "last_name": "Holt",
            "lat":"25.6599899",
            "lng":"45.3664646",
            "status":"0"

        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "first_name": "Charles",
            "last_name": "Morris",
            "lat":"25.99899",
            "lng":"45.4646",
             "status":"1"

        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "first_name": "Tracey",
            "last_name": "Ramos",
            "lat":"25.2339899",
            "lng":"45.56664646",
            "status":"1"

        }
    ]
}

import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from '../service/data.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
import {Alert} from 'selenium-webdriver';






declare var google: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tracking',
  templateUrl: './tracking.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tracking.component.css']
})
export class TrackingComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {


  public LocData: any;
  public DriversData: any;
  public location: any;
  public drivers: any;
  public mapObject: any;
  public markers: any = [];
  mapData: any;

  markerName: any;


  timer: any;

  response: any;
   public zoomlevel:any=13;

  public latlng:any={lat:25.204849,lng:55.270783};

  public locLatlng:any;
  public loczoomlevel:any;

  public getloclng:any;
  public getzoomlevel:any;
  public mapOptions:any;
  public mapCenter:any;




  constructor(public serv: DataService, private router: Router, public spinner: NgxSpinnerService) {

    // this is for loading the locations data
    this.spinner.show();
    this.serv.LoadLocation().subscribe(res => {
      this.spinner.hide();
      this.LocData = res.Data;
     // console.log(this.LocData);
      this.location = this.LocData[0].Id;
      this.onLoChange(this.location);
    }, err => {
      this.spinner.hide();

    });

   //
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {this.getMapData(this.drivers, this.location); }, 30000);




    this.getMapData(this.drivers, this.location);



  }


  onLoChange(data) {
   // console.log('Location', data);
    this.driverLoadData(data);
    //this.location = event.target.value;
    this.getMapData(this.drivers, this.location);
  }

  onDriverChange(event) {
    //console.log('Driver Id', event.target.value);
    this.drivers = event.target.value;
    this.getMapData(this.drivers, this.location);

  }

  driverLoadData(data) {
    this.spinner.show();
    this.serv.LoadDrivers(data).subscribe(res => {
      this.spinner.hide();
      //console.log(res);
      this.DriversData = res.Data;

      this.drivers = this.DriversData[0].Id;

    }, err => {
      this.spinner.hide();
      alert('Unable to load Driver Data');
    });

  }





  getMapData(data, dataOne) {
   // this.spinner.show();
    this.serv.getMapData(data, dataOne).subscribe(res => {
      //this.spinner.hide();
      this.deleteMarkers();



      debugger;

      if (res.Data && res.Data.length > 0) {
        // do something
        this.mapData = res.Data;
       // console.log(JSON.stringify(this.mapData));
        // rendering markers

        if (this.mapData != null && this.mapData.length > 0) {
          for (let i = 0; i < this.mapData.length; i++) {
            this.latlng = {lat: parseFloat(this.mapData[i].latitude), lng: parseFloat(this.mapData[i].longitude)};
            this.addMarker(this.latlng, this.mapObject, this.mapData[i].Name);
            this.markerName = this.mapData[i].Name;


          }
        }
      } else {

       // this.response = 'No Data Exist';
        alert('No Data Exist');
      }

    }, err => {
      //this.spinner.hide();
      alert('Unalbe to display data');
    });


  }

  addMarker(latlng, mapobj, markerLabel) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      label: '',
      map: mapobj,
//animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    });




    const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: markerLabel
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
     // infowindow.open(Map,marker);
    });

    infowindow.open(Map, marker);





    const styless = [
      {
        "featureType": "poi.attraction",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },

      {
        "featureType": "poi.medical",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.park",
        "elementType": "labels.text",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.place_of_worship",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.school",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "featureType": "poi.sports_complex",
        "stylers": [
          {
            "visibility": "off"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]

    mapobj.setOptions({styles: styless});




    // This is for set postion for the marker after getting dynamic data it posittions to the point
   mapobj.setZoom(14);
   mapobj.panTo(marker.position);
    this.markers.push(marker);

  }





// Sets the map on all markers in the array.
  setMapOnAll(map) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.markers.length; i++) {
      this.markers[i].setMap(map);
      this.markers[i].setPosition(this.markers[i].position);

    }
  }

  // Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
  clearMarkers() {
    this.setMapOnAll(null);
  }


  // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
  deleteMarkers() {
    this.clearMarkers();
    this.markers = [];
  }





  ngOnInit() {


   this.mapOptions ={

      zoom:this.zoomlevel,
      center: this.latlng,
      gestureHandling: 'greedy'
   }

    this.mapObject = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'),this.mapOptions );

    var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
    trafficLayer.setMap(this.mapObject);

    this.addMarker(this.latlng, this.mapObject, 'Current Location');



  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }




}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [event-properties](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-properties) and use `map.getZoom()` to get the zoom level dynamically. 
Update your `addMarker` function

```
  addMarker(latlng, mapobj, markerLabel,zoomLevel){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      label: '',
      map: mapobj,
      zoom:zoomLevel,
      //animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    });
  }
```

Update `getMapData(data, dataOne)`  inside loop

```
if (this.mapData != null && this.mapData.length > 0) {
 this.zoomlevel=this.mapObject.getZoom();
  for (let i = 0; i < this.mapData.length; i++) {
    this.latlng = {
      lat: parseFloat(this.mapData[i].latitude),
      lng: parseFloat(this.mapData[i].longitude)
    };
    this.addMarker(this.latlng, this.mapObject, this.mapData[i].Name,this.zoomlevel);
    this.markerName = this.mapData[i].Name;
  }
}
```

Update your `ngOnInit`

```
this.addMarker(this.latlng, this.mapObject, 'Current Location',this.zoomlevel);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-google-maps?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts) demo

Updated Demo with OP data

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-google-maps-ecq5gp?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Actually whats happening here is dynamically im placing markers ok for every 15 seconds i calling the getmapdata() so that the data get updated for every 15 seconds here the issue is suppose there are 10 markers are placed n the map with a radius of 2-10 km while i zoom in to a particular marker it is ok but refresh happens for 15 sec so when marker refreshes the map is flickering /changing the position to the max markers rather than the marker which im currently seeing

Comment: it should focus to last marker in the loop rather than what you are seeing currently

Comment: yeah please check the updated question with dynamic data suppose i there  1,2,3,4,5 markehrs  4th markers is travelling if i focus on 4th focus n this one when the data is updated then the focus should be this one only rather than presently my map is flickering it postion to max markers

Comment: at present when ever my update happens it is jumping the positions like suddenly its dragging its position is there any way to move smoothly

Comment: `getPosition()` check https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=pt-br and use `this.mapObject.panTo(this.marker.getPosition());`  to the marker which you want to focus

Comment: Dynamically i can check any marker Focus right? and when data refresh happens why maps shakes ?

Comment: check this update https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-google-maps-ecq5gp?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts i do not get any shakes

Comment: ok here you are displaying dynamic markers suppose u are zooming to marker and click update what is happening all the marker are centering to location thats not to be happened if you are zooming to one marker and press update then also it should display the same marker only if it is moving also iit is has to show that one only like any marker we see and press update it has to show that particular marker only

Comment: @Madpop, You hard describing you problem 

Comment: @Yerkon as per my understanding OP want to reserve focus on particular marker even if the marker is updated. Suppose If older marker  say (lat, lng) doesn't available in current set of marker. How It is possible. I have given answer for retain zoom level and to focus on the last marker in the current set of markers.